# write text combine two language Arabic and English in prawn rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

i need write text combine two language for example 
use `require 'arabic-letter-connector'`

```
    text_direction :rtl # ltr
    long_text = " Algorithm & Data Structure مرحبا يا العالم"
    text long_text.connect_arabic_letters
```

if use  `text_direction :rtl`  appear correct Arabic word but English appear `A & ataD erutcurtS`

when use `text_direction :rtl`
[image: rtl]

when use `text_direction :ltr`
[image]

i need combine Arabic and English  for example of expected result look like

```
Algorithm & Data Structure مرحبا يا العالم
```

I try fonts `Cairo`, `KacstOne`, `Amiri`

My environment

```
ruby "2.4.2"
gem 'rails', '5.1.4'
# pdf generate
gem 'prawn'
gem 'prawn-table', '~> 0.2.2'
gem 'arabic-letter-connector', '~> 0.1.1'
```

Comment: Maybe you could try to set the text_direction to :ltr first and add the English text to the long_text variable then set text_direction :rtl and then add the Arabic text.

Comment: @Smek when try this appear every text in the line but i need text like `Algorithm & Data Structure مرحبا يا العالم
`

Comment: How does the expected result look like?

Comment: @Stefan i need appear together  i update question please review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem after many search . use `connect_arabic_letters` & `String#reverse`

```rb
['مرحبا','hello','welcome', 'الجميع'].join(',').connect_arabic_letters.reverse
```

**notes**

- use font support Arabic word like `Amiri`